# How can I create a stream of my screen on a Windows computer for another device on my network?

Tags: streaming, video-conversion, video-streaming, mirroring, capture

I want to view what is seen on my Windows laptop screen on my tv, which is connected to a device running enigma 2, "screen mirroring". There are no software or plugins that will work on the device for this.

However the device can play live stream urls of the form:

http://portal.geniptv.com:8080/live#/abc1/abc2/19517.ts

I am thinking maybe I could get something to create an expanding .ts file that's capturing the screen, and then serve this up through http?

It may also be able to use other protocols like udp:// or other file extensions, I would certainly give them a shot if they reduced lag.

I spent hours installing different streaming software, none of which worked. I am just looking for a simple solution where I might give ffmpeg a command and it would do all I require. I have python installed as well if I need that to for example set up a http server.

Comment: Have you tried VLC?

Comment: Yes, but VLC only let me capture the screen (no audio), and I couldn't find a way to stream the .ts file at the same time as I was capturing it. It seems like a basic thing to want to do... to capture and stream video, I'm really surprised there isn't a basic, generic way of doing it. But all these softwares like OBS seem only set-up to stream to big corporate sites like twitch with no clear way to stream it with a http address.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try using an HDMI splitter. But if the distance is too much, ive heard that there are programs for broadcasting displays as bluetooth if the device supports them.